# Is it possible to make a freebusy query to the Google Calendar API with a template literal in the request body?

Tags: javascript, json, google-calendar-api, string-literals, google-apis-explorer

```js
var freeRequest = gapi.client.calendar.freebusy.query({
                "items": [
                    {"id": calendarid}
                ],
                "timeMin": `"${date.value}T${startTime.value}:00.000Z"`,
                "timeMax": `"${date.value}T${endTime.value}:00.000Z"`,
                "timeZone": "GMT+01:00",
            });
```

I want to check if a calendar is busy via the [freebusy query](https://developers.google.com/calendar/v3/reference/freebusy/query)

I know the request only works with the date format: YYYY-MM-DDTHH:MM:SS.MMMZ .
My plan was to paste the value that I get from an html input into a string literal and then format it accordingly. When I console.log:

```js
`"${date.value}T${endTime.value}:00.000Z"`
```

The console gives me the date in the right format (e.g. "2021-03-31T18:29:00.000Z"). But when sending the request in my application it gives me a 400 bad request error. I guess the problem lies in the string literal because the timeMin and timeMax values should only have quotation marks around it and not the

```js
``
```

I also tried saving the date in a variable, but this also did not work.
Is there a way to solve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to replicate your issue using Apps Script since it also uses Javascript. Your findings are correct, when you use the template literals, the request parameter `timeMin` and `timeMax` becomes a string rather than a `datetime` format. What I do was to concatenate the string using (+) operator and it works.

### Sample Code:

```
  var calendarId = "sample@group.calendar.google.com";
  var date = {
    value: "2021-04-03"
  }
  var startTime = {
    value: "01:00"
  }
  var endTime = {
    value: "05:00"
  }
  
 // Bad request
  var resource1 = {
    timeMin: `"${date.value}T${startTime.value}:00.000Z"`,
    timeMax: `"${date.value}T${endTime.value}:00.000Z"`,
    items: [
      {
        id: calendarId
      }
    ],
    timeZone: "GMT+08:00"
  };

  Logger.log(resource1);

  // Successful request
  var resource2 = {
    timeMin:  date.value+"T"+startTime.value+":00.000Z",
    timeMax: date.value+"T"+endTime.value+":00.000Z",
    items: [
      {
        id: calendarId
      }
    ],
    timeZone: "GMT+08:00"
  };
  Logger.log(resource2);
  var request = Calendar.Freebusy.query(resource2);
  Logger.log(request);
```

### Output:

```
6:38:55 AM  Notice  Execution started
6:38:56 AM  Info    {items=[{id=sample@group.calendar.google.com}], timeMax="2021-04-03T05:00:00.000Z", timeMin="2021-04-03T01:00:00.000Z", timeZone=GMT+08:00}
6:38:56 AM  Info    {items=[{id=sample@group.calendar.google.com}], timeMax=2021-04-03T05:00:00.000Z, timeMin=2021-04-03T01:00:00.000Z, timeZone=GMT+08:00}
6:38:56 AM  Info    {timeMax=2021-04-03T05:00:00.000Z, calendars={sample@group.calendar.google.com={busy=[]}}, kind=calendar#freeBusy, timeMin=2021-04-03T01:00:00.000Z}
6:38:57 AM  Notice  Execution completed
```

- Notice that the `timeMin` and `timeMax` becomes a string in the `resource1` variable while in `resource2` they are not in string format